# Using Swift join method to modify second to last joiner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a series of animals in an array that I am joining via a `,`.

However, I want the last animal to have an `and` before it, like so:

`cow, giraffe, horse, mongoose, leopard, and snake`.

The join method in Swift gives me everything except the `and`, and I am not sure how I can add any specifiers.

Sorry if this is a noob question, still getting the hang of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write you own join function like this:

```
func myjoin(separator: String, var elements:[String]) -> String {
    elements[elements.count - 1] = "and " + elements[elements.count - 1]
    return elements.joinWithSeparator(separator)
}

var animals = ["cow", "giraffe", "horse", "mongoose", "leopard", "snake"]

myjoin(", ", elements: animals)
```

---

Here's a version that does the "right thing" for lists with 1 or 2 elements:

```
func myjoin2(var elements:[String]) -> String {
    let count = elements.count
    let separator = (count == 2) ? " " : ", "
    if count > 1 {
        elements[count - 1] = "and " + elements[count - 1]
    }

    return elements.joinWithSeparator(separator)
}

myjoin2(["cat"])               // "cat"
myjoin2(["cat", "dog"])        // "cat and dog"
myjoin2(["cat", "dog", "pig"]) // "cat, dog, and pig"
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. You now have to use the `joinWithSeparator(String)` method